# WebBrowser control displaying markup instead of page

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have a .NET(C#) WebBrowser control that is being populated via `XSL/XML` from a DB call.  On my PC this control shows me the page as expected however when installed on another PC it simply shows the markup. 
 Any ideas why this could be?
  This will be installed for domain users to use, so could it be a security issue?  As well, this user is using Windows 2000 I believe.

In the event it is useful, I've added the code which does the work.

```
kioskID = Convert.ToInt16(cboKiosks.SelectedValue);
string kioskName = cboKiosks.SelectedText;
try
{
  using (Database d = new Database())
  {
    // Create the database objects.
    d.Command.CommandText = reportName;
    d.Command.Parameters.Add("@Start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpStartDate.Value;
    d.Command.Parameters.Add("@Stop", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpStopDate.Value;

    if (kioskID == -1)
      d.Command.Parameters.Add("@KioskID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = System.DBNull.Value;
    else
      d.Command.Parameters.Add("@KioskID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = kioskID;

    if (kioskSite == "**ALL SITES**")
      d.Command.Parameters.Add("@Site", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = System.DBNull.Value;
    else
      d.Command.Parameters.Add("@Site", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = kioskSite;

    // Load the XML.
    d.Connection.Open();
    XPathDocument xp = new XPathDocument(d.Command.ExecuteXmlReader());
    d.Connection.Close();

    System.Uri u = new Uri(Application.StartupPath);
    string folder = u.ToString();

    // Transform the XML to a CSV-formatted string.
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XsltArgumentList xa = new XsltArgumentList();                        
    xa.AddParam("When", "", System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
    xa.AddParam("ImageFolder", "", folder);
    XslCompiledTransform xt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xt.Load(templateName);
    xt.Transform(xp, xa, sw);

    webBrowser.DocumentText = sw.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Im not sure your code dump adds any value to the post. Does it work on the other machine if you just webBrowser.DocumentText = @"<html><body>Hello World</body></html>";

Comment: The code does indeed work as the application works as expected on another system.  I'm having someone check the service pack on the problem PC.  I don't think it is a code issue but either a security or local issue...

How does the webbrowser control work?  Is it using an embedded browser or simply embedding the local machines browser into the application?